# Show button on actionsheet, if IOS 6 installed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, ios6

I have an actionsheet created, and I want to display the Facebook sharing option. I dont want to use the Composeviewcontroller. My question is: Is it possible to only show the Facebook share option if the user has IOS6 installed? Code snippets would be very useful. 
I added the social framework and created an actionsheet with some buttons:

> UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
>   initWithTitle:@"Empfehlen" delegate:(id)self
>   cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen" destructiveButtonTitle:nil
>   otherButtonTitles:@"via Mail", @"via iMessage/SMS",@"Tweet", nil];

Does have anyone suggestions or solutions what to do?

My App uses iOS 5 and I would like to keep it.

Thanks.

Comment: You may also wish to use a `UIActivityViewController` on iOS 6 instead of a `UIActionSheet`.

Comment: I mean exactly what I said. Have a look at the docs for `UIActivityViewController`. It's the new way to present these types of options. On an iOS 6 device, run the Photos app and choose to share a photo for an example. The popup with all the icons is a `UIActivityViewController`. Much nicer than showing an action sheet.

Comment: well yes, youre right, but what is if the user doesnt use ios6? like on Iphone 3gs?

Comment: See my answer below to see how you use either a UIActivityViewController or UIActionSheet depending on the user's device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an answer to a follow-up question made by the OP in the comments section.

Under iOS 6+ you can use a `UIActivityViewController` while under iOS 5 earlier you can still use a `UIActionSheet`.

```
Class avcClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIActivityViewController");
if (avcClass) {
    NSArray *items = @[ xxx ]; // create one or more activity item objects for this
    UIActivityViewController *avc = [[avcClass alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:abc animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    // create and show an action sheet
}
```

Comment: well this could be helpful...I will awnser in a few minutes after I tested it...Thanks

Comment: Thanks it worked! :D But I have to look up how to set the objects in it :D

Comment: Look at the docs for `UIActivityTypePostToFacebook` and the other related constants. The data depends on what you are trying to post.

Comment: Just for example: I would like to import some text, but the text in the mail should be different from the twitter text, how can I do that?

Comment: It would be best to start a new question on this new topic.

Answer (score 2):

UIActionSheet *actionsheet;

```
if([SLComposeViewController class] != nil)//some class only available in ios6
{
    actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Empfehlen" delegate:(id)self 
cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"via Mail", @"via iMessage/SMS",@"Tweet", @"Facebook", nil];
}
else
{
    actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Empfehlen" delegate:(id)self 
cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"via Mail", @"via iMessage/SMS",@"Tweet", nil];
}
```

You're just checking if what you want to share exists and if it does show the option.

Comment: BUT THERES ONE PROBLEM!! THE ACTION WHICH IS ON THE FACEBOOK BUTTON DOESNT WORK!!! HELP